# Understanding uWSGI threads

Tags: multithreading, uwsgi

I'm very new to Python and uWSGI. I'm trying to understand how uWSGI and threads work. I got confused by some of the statements in uWSGI documents. Example:

> By default the Python plugin does not initialize the GIL. This means your app-generated threads will not run. If you need threads, remember to enable them with enable-threads. Running uWSGI in multithreading mode (with the threads options) will automatically enable threading support. This “strange” default behavior is for performance reasons, no shame in that.

I created a [test project](https://github.com/aug70/uwsgi-test) to see this in action, a very simple app that uses a ThreadExecutor pool where threads are not allowed by uWSGI ini file.

When you run the test, uWSGI logs that it starts with multiple processes and one core (wth?, I assume this is thread in their lingo?), it seems like threads are executing just fine.

My question is why is this working even when threads are NOT allowed explicitly in the uWSGI configuration? What's the downside of using threads in such context where threads are not allowed?

Comment: The problem is that uwsgi does not initialize GIL. This can have some horrible consequences in multithreaded environment. Basically this means that your app is no longer thread safe. At best you may encounter random segfaults. At worst you will have undefined behavior. For example random memory leaks because reference counter of an object will never go to 0 (due to race condition). Everything that is shared between threads is potentially broken now.